# MySQL query: select records with highest value in group

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this.

```
| season_id | round_1 | names  | score_round_1
| 5         | 10      | John1  | 5  
| 5         | 10      | John2  | 3
| 5         | 11      | John3  | 2
| 5         | 11      | John4  | 5
```

I want to select the records with highest score_round_1 in each round_1(10,11) group .

In this case the first and last rows would be selected.

I tried using the GROUP BY round_1 but that only returns the first row from the two.

Any advice?

Zolka

Answer (score 1):

This is simple

```
select max(score_round_1),
       name
from score
group by round_1
```

Comment: This does not return the correct row data of the max record of a group.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate function [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)

```
SELECT names, MAX(score_round_1) GROUP BY round_1
```

Comment: I tried already this, it returns the highest score_round_1 but I returns the first names. i.e. It would probably return John1 - 5 and John3 - 5 which is not correct.

Comment: @Zolka I'm afraid I can't get you.. You'd like to also include the name?

Comment: Yes, actually I need the highest score_round_1 and it's name, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: It returns the max values from score_round_1 (which is correct) but always the first name is selected (which is incorrect) .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table p1
WHERE score_round_1 = (
SELECT MAX( p2.score_round_1 )
FROM table p2
WHERE p1.round_1  = p2.round_1  ) ANDround_1 !=0
```

Comment: I have only 1 table but in your query I see 2 tables p1 and p2? Can you clarify?